# Setting an Object to HTML iFrame and access the elements inside its document

Tags: html, vba, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape an intranet website (since intranet I cannot share the link, sorry about that) which is structured as follows:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myIframe">#document</iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically the information that I'm looking for are inside the document of the `iframe` object. In the webpage, if I try to access it this way via JavaScript, I'm able to do it:

```
document.getElementById("myIframe").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

However, if I try to do the same in VBA, I'm unable just because the object `Set test2 = oHtml.getElementById("myIframe")` is `Nothing`.

The way I've defined `test2` is the following:

First, I've got the HTML document of the webpage via XMLHTTP request:

```
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, oHtml As Object, pontod As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", websiteLink, False
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
```

Hence, I've declared `test2` as object and tried to set it as follows:

```
Dim test2 As Object
Set test2 = oHtml.getElementById("myIframe")
```

Again, the problem is that the above `test2` sets to `Nothing` while it's not the case if I try to do the same on JavaScript (directly on the webpage).

May it depend on the fact that the HTML document I get in VBA is coming from a `WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1` request? Does anyone have any idea to work-around this problem and get the document of `myIframe`?

P.s. I understand it's not nice to work "on a black box" but unfortunately this is an intra-net; please do not hesitate to ask if you need any other information (as long as I can provide it :) )

Comment: Did you wait for the document in `oHTML` to load and render?  You should also verify that the source you get from the WinHTTPRequest is equivalent to what you're working with in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TimWilliams. I've waited for the document to load (with the usual `Do While not ready`), do you think that a good equality test might be to compare my `oHTML` with, for example, an `browserObject.document` after browsing the page with an `internetexplorer.application`?

Comment: That might work.  Or use fiddler to compare the two responses.  Hard to say exactly since I'm guessing you simplified the HTML in your question...

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, that's simplified. Thanks a lot for the tip, I'll try to do this and get back to you with the information.

Comment: @TimWilliams Just tried out with an internet explorer application object via VBA and got the correct result. I hence guess the HTML response given by the XMLHTTP request was not the same than what I saw on my browser (which is instead the document I've got with `appIE.document`). Could you please write your tip as an answer so I'll accept it? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you wait for the document in oHTML to load and render?

You should also verify that the source you get from the WinHTTPRequest is equivalent to what you're working with in javascript.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Indeed, the source I've got from the WinHTTPRequest was not equivalent to the one working in JavaScript. I've hence got the good source with a browser object (`Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")`, `appIE.Navigate myLink`, `Set HTMLsrc = appIE.document`) and got my elements in `HTMLsrc.frames("myiFrame").document`.